# "visit named_route_path" throws ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this route setup in a Rails 3.1.12 app:

```
  get '/compte/activer/:username/:token' => 'create_user#activate', :as => :create_user_activate
```

Here's the request spec:

```
describe "#activate with valid token" do
  it "activates the account" do    
    user = User.create_basic("conradk", "email@email.com", "Conrad K.", "password", "password", "Hello world!")

    visit create_user_activate_path(:username => user.username, :token => user.activation_token)

    page.should have_content(I18n.t('activerecord.success.messages.account_activated'))
  end
end
```

Here's the controller:

```
class CreateUserController < ApplicationController
  def activate username, token

  end
end
```

When I run the specs, I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: visit create_user_activate_path(:username => user.username, :token => user.activation_token)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class CreateUserController < ApplicationController
  def activate

  end
end
```

Comment: Oh right, I'm still used to Symfony style routing (coming from PHP). Thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your controller method should be defined like below:

```
class CreateUserController < ApplicationController
  def activate
    #params will have your username and token
    user_name = params[:username]
    token = params[:token]
  end
end
```